# Closing the login dialog when user is verified?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Pretty new at MVVM, so excuse the clumsiness of my code...

My program (App.xaml.cs) starts out by opening the main window (MainView)

```
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {            
        Window window = new MainView();
        window.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
        window.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
        window.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
        window.Show();

        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
```

and the constructor of MainView starts out by opening the login dialog (LoginView)

```
        public MainView()
    {
        var login = new LoginView();
        login.DataContext = new LoginViewModel();
        DataContext = new MainViewModel();
        login.ShowDialog();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

In my LoginViewModel (this is probably the wrong place for it, but I'll be refactoring to be more MVVM compliant later on) I verify the password

```
            if (user.PasswordHash == newHash)
        {
            MyGlobals.userLoggedIn = user.UserName;
            ShowMessageBox("Hurra.");
        }
```

and when that's done I want to close the dialog, which would leave me with the MainView again - I've tried just about everything I can think of, but... my inexperience is definitely holding me back.

Any ideas on how I can approach this? Google hasn't been that much of a help so far...

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/191182/login-modal-with-mvvm-pattern

Answer (score 0):

The MVVM purest way of closing a View from its ViewModel is via an attached property.

```
public static class perWindowHelper
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CloseWindowProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "CloseWindow",
        typeof(bool?),
        typeof(perWindowHelper),
        new PropertyMetadata(null, OnCloseWindowChanged));

    private static void OnCloseWindowChanged(DependencyObject target, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (!(target is Window view))
        {
            return;
        }

        if (view.IsModal())
        {
            view.DialogResult = args.NewValue as bool?;
        }
        else
        {
            view.Close();
        }
    }

    public static void SetCloseWindow(Window target, bool? value)
    {
        target.SetValue(CloseWindowProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool IsModal(this Window window)
    {
        var fieldInfo = typeof(Window).GetField("_showingAsDialog", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        return fieldInfo != null && (bool)fieldInfo.GetValue(window);
    }
}
```

Usage is

```
<Window x:Class= ...
    vhelp:perWindowHelper.CloseWindow="{Binding ViewClosed}">
```

which is bound to a corresponding `bool?` property on your ViewModel, that you set to true when you want to close the View.

More details on my [blog post](http://peregrinesview.uk/mvvm-navigation/).

Comment: Thanks @Peregrine - this looks good - but it doesn't seem to work for me and I'm not quite sure why...
I added bool? ViewClosed = true; to my viewmodel just under ShowMessagebox("Hurrah) and... nothing

Comment: for binding, it needs to be a public property that implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: this isn't working... 
`       private bool? _viewClosed;
        public bool? ViewClosed
        {
            get => _viewClosed;
            set 
            {
                _viewClosed = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(() => ViewClosed);
            }
        }`

Comment: That looks fine to me. Is the `OnCloseWindowChanged()` method being hit?

Comment: hmm, actually no :-/

Comment: there's access to the class - CloseWindowProperty is the first thing that happens when I start the app - but I've peppered the rest of the class with breakpoints and nothing...

Comment: It's got to be something with the binding - ViewClosed is being updated, but nothing's happening after that:
    <Window.....
            xmlns:me="clr-namespace:TimeKeepr.WPF.ViewModels"
            xmlns:vhelp="clr-namespace:TimeKeepr.WPF.Helper"
            vhelp:perWindowHelper.CloseWindow="{Binding ViewClosed}"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Title="TimeKeepr - Login" Height="600" Width="450" ResizeMode="NoResize" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
        <Window.Resources>
            <me:LoginViewModel x:Key="viewModel"/>
        </Window.Resources>

Answer (score 0):

You can use a NuGet package called [MvvmDialogs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmDialogs/) for all dialog related operations. The one capable of opening modal dialogs is called `ShowDialog`. You can see an example of it [here](https://github.com/FantasticFiasco/mvvm-dialogs/blob/master/samples/net-core/Demo.ModalDialog/MainWindowViewModel.cs#L42).